# Using R, how to find the line number of a specific phrase in a file without opening the file?

Tags: r

I am new to R. I have a large (3.2 Gb) txt file containing two columns. First column has the human genome sequence position and the Second column has a value corresponding to each position. I want to find the line numbers for specific positions from the first column and then read those lines into a table in R. I cannot import the file because of memory issue. here is an example of the R code I tried to get the line number of one specific position from the first column of my data file.  the data file is called my.data.

```
con <- file("my.data",open="r");
grep("13108", con)
```

grep does not work.

I will appreciate if someone can tell me the correct code.

Comment: you have to read in the file first.  You can do it chunks at a time, but `R` will not be the most efficient tool for this.

Comment: I suspect you might be happier using a different tool than R to do this.

Comment: I would echo what @RicardoSaporta and @joran said, with the caveat that you may be able to do a system call to `awk` or `sed` or similar from your R source file and thereby keep everything in once place.

Answer (score 5):

Try something along the lines of:

```
read.csv(pipe("grep 13108 my.data"), ...)
```

(fill the parameters appropriately for your data)